# How to write a listbox's data in a file.txt

Tags: python, list, sqlite, tkinter, python-3.6

I can't write in a file called `"nuovo_file"` of the records I see in a listbox I've called `"dovutolist"`. The file gets created but it doesn't write any data.

The code is this one:

```
   def Salva_File():
        percorso_file=tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile().name
        lista=list(dovutolist.get(0,END))
        print(lista)
        nuovo_file=open(percorso_file,"w")

        for i in range(len(lista)):
            nuovo_file.write(lista[i]+'\n')
        nuovo_file.close
```

The error I get is this one:

```
nuovo_file.write(lista[i]+'\n')
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: use `print( lista[i] )` to check what you have in variable - error shows that is tuple, not string. Maybe you have to get one of element from this tuple - ie. `lists[i][0]` or `lists[i][1]`.

Comment: BTW: instead of `for i in range(len(lista)): write( lists[i] )` you can use - `for item in lista: write( item )` - it is more readable.

Comment: BTW: you don't have to convert to list to save it. And you forgot `()` in `nuovo_file.close()`.

Comment: If you're using `asksaveasfile`, you don't need to call `open`, the file will be automatically opened for you.

Comment: the print (list) in video gives me [(1, '2015', '04070870870', 'RESTAURANT A CASA DI SALVO AND LUCA DI SAPIENZA S & VIA FONDACO 4 BELPASSO', '41 .60 ')]

Comment: so it works   for i in range (len (lista)):
                nuovo_file.write(str(lista[i])+'\n')
            nuovo_file.close()

Answer (score 0):

After so many tests I managed to solve, at least bypassing the obstacle, I got what I wanted, here's the code:

```
def isiDovuto_stampa():
percorso_file = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile ().name
nuovo_file = open (percorso_file, "w")
conn = sqlite3.connect('isi_dovuto.db')
with conn:
    cursore = conn.cursor()
    cursore = conn.cursor()
    cursore.execute("SELECT * FROM isi_dovuto")
    while True:
        # fin tanto che True è vero, cioè il ciclo apparentemente non termina mai ...
        # as long as True is true, that is the cycle apparently never ends ...
        righe = cursore.fetchall()

        if len(righe) > 0:
        # se abbiamo delle righe, le stampa
        # if we have lines, press
            for riga in righe:

                #print(riga)
                nuovo_file.write(str(riga)+'\n''\n')

            else:
        # altrimenti interrompe forzatamente il ciclo while
        # otherwise it forcibly interrupts the while loop
                break
nuovo_file.close ()

return righe
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to write the file's name in quotes:

For example:

```
nuovo_file=open('file_name.txt','w')
```

You should also be aware that write (w) will also overwrite all the data the next time you enter into the program. You can use append (a+) to write more than one time. This retains the previous data.

Comment: _"you have to write the file's name in quotetion marks"_ is not a true statement. OP is using a variable, which is perfectly fine.